# Non standard evaluation with S4 methods in R

Tags: r, r-s4

I am trying to implement an S4 object that has methods that use non-standard evaluation in a similar fashion as data.table does.

```
D <- data.table(x = 1:10, u = letters[1:10])
D[i = u == "a"] ## i is not evaluated in the global environment but later in the data.table package
```

Non standard evaluation seems to be possible for S4 methods which dispatch is unique:

```
setGeneric("tfun", function(x, y) standardGeneric("tfun"))
setMethod("tfun", c("character", "ANY"), function(x, y) print(x))
tfun("A", o + z + blahblah())
```

However when I add a Method that dispatches on the second argument I get an error because R tries to evaluate it.

```
setMethod("tfun", c("integer", "vector"), function(x, y) print(x))
tfun("A", o + z + blahblah()) ## Fails
```

This is especially limiting when reimplementing the "[" operator.
I understand using S3 class is an alternative. Is there a better workaround that would still use S4?

Comment: If you want to dispatch on an argument, you want that argument to be evaluated (how could R know which method to dispatch?). This could lead also to problems if the argument is of a class in the calling environment and of another class in your object environment: the wrong method will be dispatched. Maybe you could work around this way: make `tfun` a normal function (not a generic), evaluate the arguments in a no-standard way and then dispatch using a generic (which you could also not export, if you are writing a package).

Comment: @nicola My question applies to generics that where not defined by me. I should have been more precise and limit the use case to reimplementing "[". The dispatch for "[" happens on all its arguments which makes it impossible to have an S4 object behaving like data.table. A user doesn't really care about "[" being dispatched on 'drop' for example. Also on my example above the only possibility for a call where the first argument is character is the first method. Even though I add a method that doesn't make the call ambiguous it starts failing. It would be a nice feature if it didn't.